# How do i know if a SingleSelectionModel.getSelectedObject() will be NULL?

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

Let me explain.

```
SingleSelectionModel<UsuarioDTO> selectionModel = 
new SingleSelectionModel<UsuarioDTO>();

@Override
public UsuarioDTO getUsuarioSelecionado() {
   return selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
}
```

I Call this when I want to get the selected UsuarioDTO, but when my application starts I dont have a UsuarioDTO selected so I will get a NullPointerException if a call this.

My question is: Can I compare something to avoid the NullPointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (yourObject.getUsuarioSelecionado() == null) {
   // do something if it is null
} else {
   // do something with the DTO
   yourObject.getUsuarioSelecionado().callSomeMethod(); 
}
```

Is that what you're looking for? Check if something is `null`?

Comment: No, i wanna know if is possible to avoid this comparation == null for example. I'm using exactly what you post, I wanna avoid this.

Comment: @BernardoVale No, you have nothing selected in the SelectionModel, so it will always return null. If you know the DTO that you want selected by default (like a first one in the list), you can select it prior to your code executing by calling `selectionModel.setSelected(someDefaultDto, true)`.

Comment: I know @Strelok, but in that case i wont know the DTO, thanks anyway I will use the == null comparation.